# PHP Mailer: Specific Confirmations Messages based on Empty Fields

Tags: php, email, message, confirmation

I have a Contact Form which submits the data using AJAX to a PHP mailer. Once the email have been sent a confirmation message is shown to the user. It works well. My problem is **how to customize the confirmation message based on which fields have been filled**.

*The form has four fields. Name (required), Subject (option list: by default 'Subscribe to Newsletter'), Email (required) and Message and there are two cases:*

1) User is only looking to get subscribed to the Newsletter. Only 'Name' and 'Email' fields are filled. **Confirmation message A**.

2) User sends an email. 'Name', 'Email' and 'Message' are filled. **Confirmation message B**.

This is my current code, shows a general confirmation message:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $asunto = strip_tags(trim($_POST["asunto"]));
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "¡Error 400 bla bla...! 
        exit;
    }

    $recipient = "name@domain.com";
    $subject = "Nauta $name";
    $email_content = "Nombre: $name\n";
    $email_content = "Asunto: $asunto\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Mensaje:\n$message\n";
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);         
        echo "¡Thank you! bla bla...";
    }
    else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "¡Error 500 bla bla...! 
    }
}
else {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "¡Error 403 bla bla...!
}
```

I tried the following structure (elseif) with no luck.

```
if ( ) {
   echo "...";
} elseif ( ) {
   echo "...";
} else {
   echo "...";
}
```

No results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to ask if message is an empty string or one blank character:

```
if  ($_POST['message']!="") {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Carmen. It didn't work but I have found the way to make it work.

```
if (empty($_POST['message'])) {
...
}
```